# How laravel relationship internally works?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have really surprised about laravel relationship  becasue it gives  result without duplicate entries while if compare to left join. 
for example recently i tried self join has many to same table

```
 public function parentMenu(){
        return $this->hasMany(Page::class,'parent_page_id','id');
    }
```

and it return following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [page_name] => Branch Details
            [page_url] => #
            [parent_page_id] => 0
            [page_type] => 1
            [created_at] => 2018-06-23 23:45:34
            [updated_at] => 2018-06-23 23:45:34
            [deleted_at] => 
            [slug] => branch_detail
            [parent_menu] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [page_name] => Add Branch Detail
                            [page_url] => add-branch
                            [parent_page_id] => 1
                            [page_type] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2018-06-23 23:45:54
                            [updated_at] => 2018-06-23 23:45:54
                            [deleted_at] => 
                            [slug] => add_branch_detail
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [page_name] => View Branch Detail
                            [page_url] => list-branch
                            [parent_page_id] => 1
                            [page_type] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2018-06-23 23:46:08
                            [updated_at] => 2018-06-23 23:46:08
                            [deleted_at] => 
                            [slug] => 
                        )

                )

        )
```

also i have tried to figure out the query

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `pages` where `pages`.`deleted_at` is null
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                )

            [time] => 0.82
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `pages` where `pages`.`parent_page_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `pages`.`deleted_at` is null
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 5
                    [4] => 7
                    [5] => 8
                    [6] => 9
                    [7] => 10
                    [8] => 11
                    [9] => 12
                )

            [time] => 0.86
        )

)
```

Now my question is suppose if i try to get same result what will be the mysql query .Since i  want to know how internally relation query works ? will it do forloop internally or else in query itself it will produce result .

Also will it execute separate query in loop to retrieve child menu list ?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel's active record implementation doesn't use joins for its relationships (well is does for some of them but that's for relationships like `belongsToMany` where it needs to use a pivot/intermediate table).

What will actually happen is Eloquent will get the related keys from the table and perform another query to get the required relationship e.g.

`Post` has many `Comment` and there are 3 posts in the db with ids `1`, `2` and `3`.

```
Post::with('comments')->get();
```

Will result in:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT * from `posts`
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `comment`.`post_id` in ('1', '2', '3')
```

It will hen go through the results from the 2nd query and match them to the models loaded from the first.

---

If you want to see what queries are being run from your Laravel app then I would suggest installing either:

- [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)
- [Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork)

Amongst other things, either of these tools will show you the queries that are being run.

Comment: .Thank you for the answer. i have one question which one is faster relationship or normal joins ?

Comment: @vision That completely depends on the query you're wanting to run. At a very base level joins are probably going to be a tiny bit faster, however, you should try and think of your application as a whole and also about how simple and easy it is to update parts of your code when needed, if your script takes more time after you've run your query and also how much load it putting on the server e.g. processing power and memory. My main advice here would be don't try to optimise your code before you need to as it can lead to other issues down the line (unless its obviously needs changing).